# http://localhost does not work, http://127.0.0.1 works

Tags: windows, php, apache-2.2, zend-framework, zend

Iam running Zend with Apache and got to see a strange behaviour....

If i type http://127.0.0.1 in my browser url, it works fine, but after typing: http://localhost, i will get a file download window, saying file type as: application/x-httpd-php

And in my httpd.conf file, i have the following under VirtualHost *:80 definition:

```
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot E:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\my_project\public

Directory E:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\my_project\public
```

Perhaps some configuration problem... can anyone guide me..

Comment: What is the content of this file if has content? Is it a php script?

Comment: It is not a php file, its name is something random string, like: FYJqRx7z.part, and its an empty file

Comment: Attach httpd.conf. All path enclose in double quotes.

Comment: sorry i cannot attach the httpd.conf file... but can anyone tell me a reason for this?

Comment: I pinged for> ping:localhost, it is fine, and pinging> ping:127.0.0.1 also is fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the httpd.conf file:

`NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which Apache.exe is located
will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.`

so change the

`DocumentRoot E:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\my_project\public`

to

`DocumentRoot "e:/zend/Apache2/htdocs/my_project/public"`

the `Directory E:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\my_project\public` is the part of the config file in which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that directory, so it has to go like this:

`<Directory "e:/zend/Apache2/htdocs/my_project/public">
    some options
</Directory>`

it would be easier to point out what's wrong if you would post the httpd.conf here, or upload it somewhere and post a link to that file

Comment: This doesn't explain why `localhost` doesn't work though

Comment: getting an application/x-httpd-php file download window is a weird error, I'm doing my best here with the things dskanth submitted

Comment: Thanks for the answers... i got my problem solved now... i have restarted the zend server after making the change in DocumentRoot statement, as addam pointed, and http://localhost  works now :)

Answer (score 3):

Check your hosts file, typically in someplace like:

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Make sure that there is an entry for localhost like this:

`127.0.0.1   localhost`

Frankly, I can't immediately see why the absence of such an entry would produce the result you report - a download of type `application/x-httpd-php` - but when something's not working, always best to dot all the i's and cross all the t's. ;-)

Comment: Yes, indeed that entry is present in my hosts file.